# Embedded SWF File with Transparent Setting Suddenly Appearing with White Background in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, flash

I've was ready to launch a project I've been working on and I just checked it in IE and for some reason the background of the embedded SWF file that was previously transparent is suddenly appearing as white.  I have not touched the code on this object in months.

Works fine in all other browsers but suddenly IE is freaking out.

Can anyone provide some input?  Note that this is embedded in an HTML widget on the site because it is an on-line builder platform.

Here is the [page link](http://thesisdesigndesk.wix.com/warrenkahn#!the-flow/c1qv3).

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <title>SWFObject - step 3</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.115", "expressInstall.swf");
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
 html {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding:0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 0;

 }
 </style>



 </head>

 <body>


 <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="671" 
 height="895">

 <param name="movie"  
 value="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/236154657/Animation_Pixel_adjustment.swf" />
 <param name=quality value=high><param name=wmode value=transparent> <param name=loop 
 value=true> <param name=scroll value=no> 

 <!--[if !IE]>-->
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 data="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/236154657/Animation_Pixel_adjustment.swf" width="671" 
 height="895" quality="high" wmode="transparent" scroll="no" >
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <p>Alternative content</p>
 <!--[if !IE]>-->
 </object>
 <!--<![endif]-->
 </object>




 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you will need to add this on head section (with your spcefic color code of-cource)

```
html, body { height:100%; background-color: #666666;}
```

Comment: Hi @Frost MaGE.  Didn't work unfortunately.  Still white in IE.

Comment: I've found the solution..... http://www.adesdesign.net/blog/tutorials/flash/how-to-make-flash-swf-transparent/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution guys!  I bypassed the swf object script and went back to the embed method.  I could have sworn I tried this before and it didn't work which is why I looked into swf object but it's working now

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <title>SWFObject - step 3</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

 <style type="text/css">

 html,body {

 overflow: hidden;
 padding:0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 background-color: transparent;
 height:100%;

 }
 </style>

 </head>

 <body>


 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" 
 width="671" height="895">
 <param name="movie" value="http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/Animation_Pixel_adjustment.swf">
 <param name="quality" value="high">
 <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
 <embed src="http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/Animation_Pixel_adjustment.swf"  
 wmode="transparent" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"  
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="671" height="895"></embed>
 </object>

 </body>

 </html>
```